# SharedPreferences does not pass get the saved value

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on android project built partially in kotlin and partially in java. I am trying to pass information from a kotlin fragment class to a java class. I have come to see that there is a problem with the passing of information as I do not receive the needed value. After some debugging I have seen that the information is successfully stored, however when the information from shared preferences is accessed, only the default value is returned.

This is the code in the kotlin class. When a button is clicked it changes the value of a boolean variable to the opposite one, sets the text of a button to true/false and saves the value of the variable in shared preferences.

```
 btnStyle.setOnClickListener() {
            styleHasChanged = !styleHasChanged;

            if(styleHasChanged  == true){
                btnStyle.setText("true")
            }else{
                btnStyle.setText("false")
            }

            val sharedPref : SharedPreferences?= activity?.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPref?.edit()?.putBoolean("bla", styleHasChanged)?.apply()
}
```

This is the java class. Shared preferences is called inside a function which chooses a filepath based on the received value.

```
 public static String getHtmlContent(Context context, String htmlContent, Config config) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("bla",MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean hasStyleChanged = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("bla", false);

    //moj
    String cssPath;


        if (!hasStyleChanged) {
            cssPath = String.format(context.getString(R.string.css_tag), "file:///android_asset/css/Style.css");
        } else {
            cssPath = String.format(context.getString(R.string.css_tag), "file:///android_asset/css/Style2.css");
        }
```

This is where the problem arises. Shared preferences in the java class always fetches the default value, no matter if the button is clicked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `context.getSharedPreferences("PreferencesFileName",MODE_PRIVATE)` should be the same even when using the `activity?.getPreferences("PreferencesFileName",MODE_PRIVATE)`. In you code it's not like that.

Plus a simple suggestion, because I'm not sure if you're clear on that. The `bla` is the key for your `boolean` value not your Preferences file name. I mean it could be, but it's better to separate.

Comment: I changed the keyword of the 'SharedPreferences' file name to something else, but the same problem is still here.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall the app. and now I will check what's wrong again

Comment: And I still believe that's the problem. Your `context.getSharedPreferences("PreferencesFileName",MODE_PRIVATE)` should be the same even when using the `activity?.getPreferences("PreferencesFileName",MODE_PRIVATE)`. In you code it's not like that

Comment: Yup you are correct I should pass the file name in both functions. getPreferences did not take the string parameter so I had to change it to getSharedPReferences. Works perfectly now.

Comment: You *can* use the same keyword for both file name and key. The correct explanation is in the answer from @earthw0rmjim

Answer (score 2):

The `getPreferences` method implicitly uses the class name of the `Activity` as the preference file name. By passing `"bla"` as the file name to `getSharedPreferences` you're trying to fetch the saved value from a different file.

If you would like to access the same preferences accross your application, then either use `getSharedPreferences` (for both writing and reading the preference) with the **same** file name, or use the [`getDefaultSharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) static method of `PreferenceManager` to obtain the default `SharedPreferences` instance.

You should change your code to something like this:

```
val sharedPref : SharedPreferences? = activity?
        .getSharedPreferences("someFileName", MODE_PRIVATE)
sharedPref?.edit()?.putBoolean("bla", styleHasChanged)?.apply()
```

And the Java part:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context
        .getSharedPreferences("someFileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean hasStyleChanged = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("bla", false);
```

Comment: Yes, this was the mistake. getPreferences was changed to getSharedPreferences and the information is passed sucesfully now.